# How to move just opened new window of an already started client to a tag automatically?

Tags: firefox, awesome-wm

The rule for starting Firefox on tag1 is working me for ages:

```
{ rule = { class = "Firefox" },
  properties = { tag = tags[1][1] }},
```

Now, with Firefox 20 it is possible to open a new Private browsing session while keeping the other session in its original window.

My rule for this is the following:

```
{ rule = { name = "Private Browsing - Mozilla Firefox (Private Browsing)" },
      properties = { tag = tags[1][9] }},
```

I've commented out my first rule, started Firefox on one of the tags but when I press CTRL+SHIFT+P in Firefox the new window still opens on the tag where the original window is.

After some testing I think the reason for this behavior is what I indicated in the question's title. There is nothing special with Firefox, and it's new feature coming in with version 20: they are just windows with some WM_CLASS(STRING) and WM_NAME(STRING)  identifiers which aren't matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rules will not work because at the moment of starting PrivateBrowser its name is "Mozilla Firefox". Awesome's rules works when awesome (re)starting or a new client appears. If a client is appeared rules will not work on this client (until you restart awesome).

But you've a possibility: the [signals of clients](https://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Signals#client).

The code:

```
-- connect a signal on new client appears
client.connect_signal("manage",function(c,startup)
  if (c.class=="Firefox") then
      -- if it's a Firefox we will connect a signal which will call if 'name' changing
      c:connect_signal("property::name",function(c)
          if (string.find(c.name,"(Private Browsing)")) then
              -- if "(Private Browsing)" is part of 'c.name' then 'c' goes to tags[1][9] 
              c:tags({tags[1][9]})
          end
      end)
  end
end)
```

It should work (I've tested).

You can check the name of clients when they appear:

```
client.connect_signal("manage",function(c,startup)
    naughty.notify({text=c.name})
end)
```

Comment: Where do I have to put this in rc.lua? At the end of that file it causes malfunction.

Comment: I think it should work (after all 'require'). What do you mean 'malfunction'? Awesome doesn't start or it start but doesn't work correctly? Maybe I've forget some close-brackets.

Comment: I think one end) is missing from the end.

Comment: Ah, yes, indeed. Thanks! I hope it works now :)

Comment: Something is wrong. Using the shipped rc.lua with Debian my tags are displayed 3 times at the top of the screen. I even "disabled" Run or raise by renaming aweror.lua and ror.lua. In theory everything was the bare config + your modifications with awesome v3.4.14 (White Christmas).

Comment: It works with 3.5.1, and I think with 3.5 too. The 3.4.14... maybe not, I don't know what was the changes.

If tags are displayed 3 times, this isn't my code's failure :)

Please check: https://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Awesome_3.4_to_3.5#Signals - I think you should rename `connect_signal` to `add_signal` and works fine.

Comment: With `add_signal` it is working.

Comment: Very good news :)